# How to convert string value to ASN.1 value

Tags: asn.1, node-forge

I'm trying to convert some values to ASN.1 format based on some examples, but I haven't success to understand some pieces of my example ASN.1 values...

First, I have the following ASN.1 value: 13024252
This value using in string format is: BR
BR in hex is the last part of the ASN.1 value: 4252

What's the 1302?

The second example is very similar:
ASN.1 value: 130d31333335333233363030313839
This value using in string format is: 1335323600189
1335323600189 in hex is the last part of the ASN.1 value: 31333335333233363030313839

What's the 130d?

I have to encode my string values because I have to create a subject_dn for a cert and some parts of the subject_dn is in ASN.1 format.
Using node-forge I can have the attribute values in string format, but couldn't convert them to ASN.1 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the 1302?

`13` (in hex) is ASN.1 type -- PrintableString

`02` (in hex) is type content length in bytes. 2 bytes. Next two bytes are type value (a string in your case). Same with your second example.

ASN.1 types are encoded using TLV (tag-length-value) structures. You can read more about this here: [DER Transfer Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-der-transfer-syntax).

Keep in mind that distinguished name is a more complex structure, it is a SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName, which in turn is a SET OF AttributeTypeAndValue:

```
DistinguishedName ::= RDNSequence

RDNSequence ::= SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName

RelativeDistinguishedName ::= SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF
    AttributeTypeAndValue

AttributeTypeAndValue ::= SEQUENCE {
    type  AttributeType,
    value AttributeValue }
```

Full schema in [X.501 InformationalFramework](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/formal-language/itu-t/x/x501/2019/InformationFramework.html)